# How to sum values associates to categories from different dataframes using python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to python and I have a simple problem, I guess

```
+---------------------------+-------+
|        Dataframe 1        |       |
+---------------------------+-------+
| Category                  | Value |
| A                         | 1     |
| B                         | 10    |


+-------------+-------+
| Dataframe 2 |       |
+-------------+-------+
| Category    | Value |
| A           | 1     |
| C           | 5     |
+-------------+-------+



╔═══════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ Result Dataframe expected ║       ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ Category                  ║ Value ║
║ A                         ║ 2     ║
║ B                         ║ 10    ║
║ C                         ║ 5     ║
╚═══════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

Any ideas?

I hope I did ok with the tables...

Edit: fixed i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('category').sum()
```

Output:

```
          value
category       
A             2
B             5
C            10
```

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'category' column is the index of the dataframes, you can use the `.add` method:

```py
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'value': [1, 5]}, index=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'value': [1, 10]}, index=['A', 'C'])
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Which outputs:

```
   value
A    2.0
B    5.0
C   10.0
```

Comment: But in the original question `category` is not an index column.

Comment: @CodePope are you 100% sure on that? the OP doesn't specify. in any case, it could easily be made into the index

Comment: If it would be an index column, I would expect that it had not a column name like `Category`.

Comment: if you're going to get meaningful alignment, you can safely consider it an index, IMO

Answer (score 0):

If you have two columns `Category` and `Value` and `Category` is not an index, then you can do it by the following code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('A',1),('B',10)], columns=['Category','Value'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([('A',1),('C',5)], columns=['Category','Value'])

df_add = df1.set_index('Category').add(df2.set_index('Category'), fill_value=0)
df_add
```

Output:

```
           Value
Category    
A          2.0
B          10.0
C          5.0
```